# Is www-data considered a non-privileged user on Apache?

Tags: security, apache-2.4, permissions

Great [Apache Hardening post](http://chandank.com/webservers/apache/apache-web-server-hardening-security?start=2) that recommends "Run Apache from non-privileged account" because "Default apache configuration is to run as nobody or daemon."

Is `www-data:www-data` considered a non-privileged account by default?
Or is it better to change to something like `apache2:apache2`?

In either case, is it best to change the Apache files from root ownership to that user?

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /etc/apache2
```

OR

```
sudo chown -R apache2:apache2 /etc/apache2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no difference at all if the Apache user is called `www-data`, `apache2` or `dumbo` (`www-data` is the default on Debian derivatives, and `apache2` on RedHat). Both are non-privileged (e.g. non-root) on their respective platforms, because that is what's important: The user needs to have as few permissions as possible in the rest of the system. The default installation/configuration on nearly all distributions for Apache automatically take care of this.

Furthermore, you should restrict the data files as much as possible, but that is often limited by other concerns like allowing users to edit the files.

Comment: Thanks.  So it is best to sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /etc/apache2 on Debian systems?  I assume you want to deny access to all except root and www-data anyway.  Is there a user I am forgetting that would need write access?

Comment: I can't tell. It's your system and you have to know who needs access to it. In many cases, I only allow read-only access for only the web server user but your requirement might differ.